# Adding, updating and removing associated classes in Grails

Tags: grails, has-many, belongs-to

I have the following relations:

```
class Host {
    static hasMany = [ips: HostIp, groups: HostGroup]
    static belongsTo = [HostGroup]
    String dns
}

class HostIp {
    static belongsTo: [host: Host]
    String ip
}

class HostGroup {
    static hasMany = [ hosts: Host ]
    String name
}
```

I have a form in a GSP that allows the edition of the host. I have a dynamic add-edit-remove list to add, edit and delete new and current host IPs, so if a host has originally two IPs (ip1 and ip2), but ip1 is removed, ip2 modified to ip3 and ip4 is added, this data is sent to the controller:

Original data displayed in the form:

```
ips[0].id = 8
ips[0].ip = ip1
ips[1].id = 9
ips[1].ip = ip2
```

Sent data when submitted:

```
ips[1].id = 9
ips[1].ip = ip3
ips[2].ip = ip4
```

This means, that, as ip1 is removed, neither its id or ip is sent (its fields are removed from the form), and a new ip4 is sent (new dynamic field added), without id, as it doesn't exist yet. So, when doing `bindData(host, params)`, and then `save()`, ip2 is updated to ip3, and ip4 is created, but ip1 is not deleted. Is this the normal behaviour of `bindData`? If not, can this be forced?

I'll ask for the groups relations in another post...

Regards and thanks in advance.

Using grails 2.3.7.

Comment: I don't think bindData would delete unmapped records. One bad way you can achieve what you are looking for is to wipe out everything and re-write the associations with new data every time, if that is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
 static mapping = {
        ips cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
 }
```

to the **Host** class. For more, see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html (*Using this configuration a Book will also be deleted if it is removed (orphaned) from an Author's books association.*)